# Cannot search for all three properties on mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

This is my first post here.
When typing on input string or number (name or surname or age) i want to find that on database (if they exist). If I type a string that will search that string (**name** or **surname**) on the database. If I type the number that will search for the **age** property in the database.

UI picture:
[UI picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5f3O.png)

Input has onChange function that forward values to the backend.
The const term is a string that I forward to the backend.

Action picture: [Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaONB.png)

When I receive constant term on backend my search not working very well.
On front when I type a number he searches for an age that has this number and it is ok.
But when I type word search does not work.

If (on backend) I comment number searching it search regularly for name and surname.

Mongoose mode picture: [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw8HC.png)

What is wrong?

Backend picture: [Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dLUl.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value from front-end check that is number or string? And if string look for the fields name and surname and if number look for age. Create an array for OR condition and push the object in that array based on input(string or number) and pass that array to OR.

Comment: Value from the front-end is a string. On the backend, I tried to convert string to number (for number filed) and the result of the query is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you use `String` for `Number` field all the time. If you dynamically create query based on the input's type, you can get correct results.

Example:

```
const anyWorOrNum = req.params.x;

// Check if anyWorOrNum is a number
const isNumber = false;

let anyNum = null;

try {
    
    anyNum = Number(anyWorOrNum); // Trying to convert string into number.

    isNumber = true; // it's a number!

} catch (err) {

    isNumber = false; // it's not a number!

}

const query = {};

// If the input is number, just create a basic query that
// only contains age search
if (isNumber) {

   query.age = anyNum;

} else {

   // Query now needs a $or operation to search in name and surname.
   query.$or = [{name: anyWorOrNum, surname: anyWorOrNum}];

}

// Use or array in find query

const users = await userModel.find(query).exec();

// Rest is same
..
..
```

Comment: I check for type on different way: const checkType = !isNaN(parseInt(anyWordOrNum, 10)); After that used if/else to chek if true find number else find string. You give me idea. Thank you

Comment: There are couple ways to do this. I'm happy to help you.